# Generating plasma flame with neon transformator

Tags: transformer, neon

I'm trying to create plasma fire with 10kV neon transformer, as shown below. The name is SIET METALBOX (10kV 30mA). How do I diagnose the problem? All wires are ok.

The issue is that the setup doesn't work as expected after connecting to an outlet (50Hz 220V). Black wires are for high voltage output, white are inputs. I expect small plasma fire at the ends of the black wires pair when the ends are sufficiently close.

[image]

Comment: "How to diagnose the problem?" You've not yet described any problem.

Comment: (aside of playing around with a 300W 10kV supply, which is seriously dangerous)

Comment: `All wires are ok.` Then why do you say that you have a problem?

Comment: `All wires are ok.` and yet you're missing the protective earth.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you expect "plasma fires"?

Comment: Unless you have experience of handling high voltages, let well alone. 10KV @ 30mA is lethal.

Answer (score 3):

10 kV AC is not going to jump very far, maybe 0.3 cm.  You will need to initiate a spark by briefly touching the leads together, then drawing them apart. Or you could build a Jacob's ladder to cause the plasma arc to travel up the rails until the gap is too wide to support the arc.

*Never handle the wires directly to avoid such unpleasantries as death by electrocution.*

Comment: My experience is that the arc can stretch out to 1cm or 2cm once it is going, as the hot plasma is a great conductor. +1 for the dire warning.

Answer (score 3):

That white box, is this a high-frequency electronic neon driver?  An "electronic transformer?"

If so, it won't work for generating plasma-flames.  It contains fire-prevention circuitry. It detects the neon sign, and if missing, refuses to turn on.

A real, non-electronic transformer at 10KV 30mA must pass 300 watts, and always includes many kilos of iron.   If your white plastic box is extremely heavy, then it's a transformer.   Otherwise, it's mostly hollow, and full of electronics (plus small ferrite inductors operating at high freq:  ~30KHz.)
[image]

Comment: The one is the picture is marked NO GFI( it's Chinese ) and would work for this, but the GFI (ground fault interrupter) is a requirement for transformers built for the US, and arc fault detection is also often found, that would shut the unit down. The smaller high frequency units also usually have open circuit detection, to prevent the creation of excessively high voltage across its internal insulation, so again would likely shut down if used in the manner intended in this question. https://www.signsofthetimes.com/content/ul-2161-faq